# Algorithm - Smallest subtraction

Tags: arrays, algorithm, list, math, time

We are given list/array (We can use both) of integers
In one move we are able to subtract two of them and put in the list/array
What's the lowest number (or the same numbers) ( > 0 ) we can get doing this operation

f.e  we have 6 4 2
First move  Take 6 and 4, We get 2 and 2, so anwser is 2

1 7 5
Take 7 and 5, we get 2 and 1, then we get 1

8 20 4 15
Take 20 and 15, we get 8 5 4, take 8 and 5, we get 4 and 3 then we get 1

I can do this in time T(n) = n^n, by comparing everything or sorting every single turn, how we may do this much faster?

Comment: If the list is already sorted couldn't you take a greedy approach and start from the end of the list then subtract the one to the left, then re insert it and continuously do that?

Comment: What have you tried so far? We won't be doing your homework for you. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Ok, so my first attempt was to compare everything with everything 
Than I was thinking about sorting list/array and using priority queue, simply adding the substraction (It didn't work)
And I was thinking about set, we always take 2 greatest and put it, when max of set equals min of set we may end, but the last one I think doesn't work
Greey approach may not work I we are no able to sort list/array in every move

Comment: I tried a few more things, and updated my answer accordingly, but I don't think you can do better than finding the largest number and then subtracting every other number from it in each step.

Answer (score 1):

Having worked on similar problems, I'm convinced there is no greedy algorithm that can guarantee an optimal result. However, it may not be necessary to look at every single combination of two numbers in every step.

Looking at a few examples, it's obvious that the first number you use should always be the largest one. For lists of 3 or 4 elements, subtracting the second-largest number is always the optimal choice. However, for lists of 5 elements or more, there seems to be no general rule.

```
10,4,3,2,1  ->  6,3,2,1  ->  3,2,1  ->  1,1  ->  1  (largest minus 2nd-largest: 10-6=4)
10,4,3,2,1  ->  9,4,3,2  ->  5,3,2  ->  2,2  ->  2  (largest minus smallest: 10-1=9)
```

```
 9,8,7,6,5  ->  1,7,6,5  ->  1,1,5  ->  1,4  ->  3  (largest minus 2nd-largest: 9-8=1)
 9,8,7,6,5  ->  4,8,7,6  ->  4,1,6  ->  2,1  ->  1  (largest minus smallest: 9-5=4)
```

I tested an algorithm which tries both the smallest and the second-largest number for each step (resulting in 2<sup>n</sup> recursions), but found an example where this doesn't work: `99,78,68,56,52,4,3`.

The best solution found by using only smallest or second-largest is 6:

```
99 78 68 56 52  4  3
96 78 68 56 52  4
92 78 68 56 52
40 78 68 56
40 10    56
   10    16
          6
```

The best solution found by brute-forcing all options is 1:

```
99 78 68 56 52  4  3
31 78    56 52  4  3
31 26    56     4  3
   26    25     4  3
    1           4  3
    1           1
```

If you use the largest number as the only optimisation, this would lead to the following algorithm:

- Find the largest number
- Iterate over every other number, subtract it from the largest number, and recurse

This would have a lower time complexity than trying every combination of two numbers, or sorting after every step.